# iFrame with Phonegap and JQuery Mobile escaping the APP to the browser

Tags: eclipse, iframe, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile-application

```
<div data-role="content">    
    <iframe src="http://drumbeat.pro/" frameborder="0" width="99%" height="100%" align="middle"></iframe>
    <form id="loginForm">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
    </form>

</div>
```

I am trying to show iFrames in my phonegap app but every link I click goes to the browser, how do I avoid that? Please dont suggest this answer ( http://denrobapps.com/2010/12/phonegap-and-iframes/ ) because the Phonegap prescreibed herewith is outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the domains of the external links to the ExternalHosts entry in PhoneGap.plist in Xcode (assuming you're working on an iOS app).

http://wiki.phonegap.com/

.

Site-note: "drumbeat.pro" -> What type of services/products does the site offer? I'm a drummer...

Comment: drumbeat is a 'multimedia agency' of some sort, go on and check it out, I am currently developing this app for all platforms